# subgroups of a group G

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a group G of order $p^2$ with p prime number. G can have $p+3$ subgroups?

G can have an element of order $p^2$ or all elements of G have order p?

Comment: To your second question yes if $G$ has an element of order $p^2$ then it is cyclic.  Otherwise all elements have order $p$ (EXCEPT the identity which has order $1$).

Comment: G can have at most $p+3$ subgroups?

Comment: Yes, if $G$ is not cyclic then it has precisely $p+3$ subgroups. This is a fairly elementary counting problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are just two groups of order $p^2$: The cyclic group $C_{p^2}$ of order $p^2$, or the direct product $C_p \times C_p$ of cyclic groups of order $p$. Yes, you can tell these apart by whether you have any elements of order $p^2$.

In simple cases like this, it's not too hard to count subgroups.

For $C_{p^2}$, we a have a unique subgroup for each divisor of $p^2$. There are only $3 = 2 + 1$ divisors of $p^2$, so we just have three subgroups  including the trivial and nonproper subgroups.

For $C_p \times C_p$, it's analogous to finding subspaces of a vector space (of dimension two over the field with $p$ elements): There are the $0$- and $2$-dimensional subspaces (which are unique), and then there are $1$-dimensional subspaces.

To count the latter, note that each nonzero vector determines a $1$-dimensional subspace, so we have at most $p^2 - 1$ subspaces. But we've overcounted, as different vectors can determine the same subspace. How many vectors determine a given subspace? Well, these subspaces have size $p$ and include the zero vector, hence there are $p - 1$ nonzero vectors in each subspaces, and our $p^2 - 1$ overcounts by a factor of $p - 1$. Thus we have $\frac{p^2 - 1}{p - 1} = p + 1$ subspaces of dimension $1$. Now including the trivial and nonproper subspaces, this does bring our total up to $p + 3$.

Instead of thinking about vectors, you could rephrase all of this to think about generators, but I personally have more intuition for vector spaces.

Comment: and if i can't use vector space?

Comment: It's the same idea, different language. There are obviously the trivial and whole group as subgroups. Then, count the cyclic subgroups (the one-dimensional subspaces, in the vector space language) with the same technique I wrote about. Then you could show that any set with two nonidentity generators either generates one of the cyclic subgroups you already counted, or the entire group, to verify that you've found all $p + 3$.